# Regex not capturing all matches

Tags: regex, yaml

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/oUbqBw/1

So, I need to get selectedSurvey (check), feedbackType (check) and name/email of each object inside the assessor's array (array can have N objects with these keys).

As you can see from the example, this is what I get on the capturing group #3:

```
`John Doe","email":"john@doe.com"},{"name":"Jane Doe`
```

I know that it's because I'm using greedy capturing groups, but I couldn't make it work even with non-greedy (got the name correctly, but couldn't capture the email).

Comment: This should better be parsed using a JSON parser

Comment: Is it possible within .yaml file?

Comment: What programming language are you using? And would it have a YAML parser?

Comment: I'm using YAML to mock a backend, with stubby4node: https://github.com/mrak/stubby4node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out, you are probably better off with a json parser. If you really must, I'd go with this regex ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/oUbqBw/3)):

```
{
  "selectedSurvey":"([^"]+)",
  "feedbackType":"([^"]+)",
  "assessors":\[
    ((?:{"name":"([^"]*)","email":"([^"]*)"},?)*)
  ]
}/mx
```

Explanation:

- the `/x` switch lets you write the regex into multiple lines. I.e. the whitepsaces will be ignored, but the expression will be more readable.
- Instead of greedy/lazy qualifiers I prefer use a negated character class: `"([^"]*)"`. It says: "A quote, then capture all non-quote characters, then another quote". This will be fine as long as you have no escaped quotes within the attributes.
- The array is a little tricky. I know no way to capture all the parts with a single regex. Probably it's impossible. However, this construct will let you match them all: `\[((?:{...},?)*)]`.

  - `{...}` will match one item in the array
  - `(?:{...},?)` will match one item and an optional comma. I.e. there will be no comma after the last array item. We don't want to capture this group. We'll capture all the repetitions instead. Thus it's a non-capture group: `(?:...)`
  - `((?:{...},?)*)` - the inner, non-capturing group has a modifier: `*`, i.e. there can be more of this stuff. Then, we capture all the repetitions with one group.
  - As a bonus, the contents of the **last** array item are in group 4 and 5. Probably you can ignore them.
  - Later you can `split` this array and parse them with this regex: `"([^"]*)"`.

Comment: Your regex captures **only the last** name and email from the assessor list (Jane Doe). You failed to capture previous instances of them.

Comment: @Valdi_Bo I mentioned this flaw in the explanation part: *As a bonus, the contents of the **last** array item are in group 4 and 5. Probably you can ignore them.*. I also explained how I suggest to resolve this flaw.

Answer (score 1):

That yaml data looks like a json.
And in javascript you can use [JSON.parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) to parse data from a JSON.

```js
var str = '{"selectedSurvey":"Performance Survey","feedbackType":"official","assessors":[{"name":"John Doe","email":"john@doe.com"},{"name":"Jane Doe","email":"jane@doe.com"}]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(str);

console.log("selectedSurvey: "+ obj.selectedSurvey);
console.log("feedbackType : "+ obj.feedbackType);
for (var i in obj.assessors) { 
   console.log("assessor "+ i +": "+ obj.assessors[i].name+ ", " +obj.assessors[i].email); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
(?<="selectedSurvey":")([^"]+)|(?<="feedbackType":")([^"]+)|(?<="name":")([^"]+)|(?<="email":")([^"]+)
```

This regex contains 4 alternatives, each containing:

- a lookbehind for an item title (in quotes), a colon and the "opening",
  quote,
- a capturing group, catching a sequence of chars other than a quote.

Each alternative has different item title: *selectedSurvey*, *feedbackType*,
*name* and *email*.

Because of `g` (global) option, each "interesting" item gets catched in
the order of appearance, by the respective capturing group.

So the source text which you included in your example gets captured
the following way:

- Capturing group 1 catches *selectedSurvey*.
- Capturing group 2 catches *feedbackType*.
- Capturing group 3 catches the first *name*.
- Capturing group 4 catches the first *email*.
- Capturing group 3 catches the second *name*.
- Capturing group 4 catches the second *email*.